# How do I count male, female and total students from Student table based on Class level in laravel using eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How do I count male, female and total students from Student table based on Class level in laravel using eloquent. I want to create something like this;

```
==================================================
| year     |  Male    |   Female   |  Total     |
==================================================
|Level 100 |   60     | 70         |     130    |
|Level 200 |  23      | 20         |     43     |
|Level 300 |  23      | 35         |     58     |
================================================
```

I tried this,
This is my controller ( I shared the data from the AppServiceProvider.php )

```
$countgender = DB::table('students')
                 ->select('students.gender', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('c_level')
                 ->get();
                 $view->with('gender', $countgender);
```

Blade Template below

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="50%">Year Group</th>
      <th scope="col">Male</th>
      <th scope="col">Female</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($gender as $gender)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$gender->c_level}}</th>
      <td>{{$gender->total}}</td>
      <td>{$gender->total}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, This is how my table is structured in my database.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        

        $table->id('std_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('student_reference_table');
        $table->string('Programme');
        $table->string('c_level');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->string('f_name');
        $table->string('f_email');
        $table->string('DoB');
        $table->string('p_address');
        $table->string('nationality');
        $table->string('region');
        $table->string('home_town');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('p_school');
        $table->string('p_location');
        $table->string('disability');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->string('fee_category');
        $table->string('religion');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('g_surName');
        $table->string('g_fname');
        $table->string('occupation');
        $table->string('gp_address');
        $table->string('p_region');
        $table->string('g_mobile');
        $table->string('g_mail');
        $table->string('std_status')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('student_reference_table')
        ->references('student_reference')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        
    });
}
```

Comment: please edit your post to share table with sample data. The one you shared doesn't have `c_level` or `gender` columns

Comment: Please I have, I just can figure out how to do it

Comment: Kindly assist me

Comment: I am trying to but you need to provide your existing table structure with the sample data. You just shared your expected output.

Comment: Please i have updated the Question

Answer (score 0):

You may use `WITH ROLLUP` to get total of grouped by rows.

```
SELECT `c_level`, IFNULL(gender, 'total') AS gender, count(*) AS sum
FROM `students`
GROUP BY `c_level`, `gender`
WITH ROLLUP
```

This is the Query builder version;

```
return DB::table('students')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('c_level, gender WITH ROLLUP'))
    ->get(['c_level', DB::raw('IFNULL(gender, "total") AS gender') , DB::raw('count(*) as sum')])
    ->reject(function ($row) {
        return !$row->c_level; // remove roll-up null value
    })
    ->groupBy('c_level'); // this one is collection's group by
```

It will print something like these; (each level's value will be key to the collection). Then you can iterate on your front end with two nested loops. First loop will be for year(rows) and the second one will be the values for gender(columns).

```
{
    "100": [{
        "c_level": "100",
        "gender": "female",
        "sum": 8
    }, {
        "c_level": "100",
        "gender": "male",
        "sum": 2
    }, {
        "c_level": "100",
        "gender": "total",
        "sum": 10
    }],
    "120": [{
        "c_level": "120",
        "gender": "female",
        "sum": 1
    }, {
        "c_level": "120",
        "gender": "male",
        "sum": 1
    }, {
        "c_level": "120",
        "gender": "total",
        "sum": 2
    }],
    "150": [{
        "c_level": "150",
        "gender": "male",
        "sum": 2
    }, {
        "c_level": "150",
        "gender": "total",
        "sum": 2
    }],
    "200": [{
        "c_level": "200",
        "gender": "female",
        "sum": 2
    }, {
        "c_level": "200",
        "gender": "male",
        "sum": 2
    }, {
        "c_level": "200",
        "gender": "total",
        "sum": 4
    }]
}
```

Comment: i tired looping through using ```@foreach``` but it isn't working. Can you please assist me with that. Am actually new and finding it difficult to do somethings. Thank you.

Comment: @PrinceAsamoah i said you need two loops and wrote the instructions for it. The question is about how to query this with eloquent - i tried to provide it. Not familiar with blade.